# Antiderivative of $g''(x)=f''(x)+\frac{1}{x^2}+e^{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f,g:(0,+\infty)$ be functions such that:

- (1) $g''(x)=f''(x)+\frac{1}{x^2}+e^{1-x}$,
- (2) $f(x) \geq g(x)-2x+2$, for all $x>0$.

Show  that $g'(1)=f'(1)+2$ and find the relation between $f$ and $g$.

First of all, from (1) we are able to find that $g'(x) =f'(x) -\frac{1}{x}-e^{1-x} +c_{1}$ and then $g(x)=f(x)-\ln x+e^{1-x}+c_{1}x+c_{2}$, where $c_{1},c_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$. I have no idea what to do with (2). I can define a function $h$ such that $h(x)=f(x) - g(x)+2x-2 \geq0$. I can also find the derivative of $h$, $h'(x)=f'(x)-g'(x)+2$. I  suppose I have to prove that $h'(1)=0$, that is $x_{0}=1$ is an extremum for $h$. Furthermore, I can show that $h''(x)<0$, that is, $h'$ is decreasing and $h$ is concave.

Comment: it should be $-\ln x$ not $+\ln x$ in the formula for $g(x)$.

Comment: yes-typo- I fixed it. Any idea how to find $c$ or to prove that $h'(1)=0$?

Comment: Well, I’m not even sure the second bullet point makes sense, since $h(x):=f(x)-g(x)+2x-2=\ln x-e^{1-x}+(2-c_1)x-(c_2+2)$, it follows that $h(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$, due to the $\ln$ term, so it is impossible for $h$ to be non-negative on $(0,\infty)$. Unless you mean $x>1$?

Comment: anyway, the two bullet points are insufficient to prove that $g’(1)=f’(1)+2$. If you’re asking whether it is possible to ensure this, the answer is obviously yes, by choosing $c_1$ appropriately; but this may then conflict with the second bullet point.